# Electron: How to securely inject global variable into BrowserWindow / BrowserView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, electron

I want to load an external webpage in Electron using `BrowserView`. It has pretty much the same API as `BrowserWindow`.

```js
const currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
const view = new remote.BrowserView({
  webPreferences: {
    // contextIsolation: true,
    partition: 'my-view-partition',
    enableRemoteModule: false,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    sandbox: true,
  },
});
view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });
view.webContents.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
```

In my `preload.js` file, I simply attach a variable to the global object.

```js
process.once('loaded', () => {
  global.baz = 'qux';
});
```

The app running on `localhost:3000` is a React app which references the value like this:

```js
const sharedString = global.baz || 'Not found';
```

**The problem is** I have to comment out the setting `contextIsolation: true` when creating the `BrowserView`. This exposes a security vulnerability.

Is it possible to (one way - from Electron to the webpage) inject variables into a `BrowserView` (or `BrowserWindow`) while still using `contextIsolation` to make the Electron environment isolated from any changes made to the global environment by the loaded content?

**Update:**
One possible approach could be intercepting the network protocol, but I'm not sure about this

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const { protocol } = session.fromPartition('my-partition')

  protocol.interceptBufferProtocol('https', (req, callback) => {
    if (req.uploadData) {
      // How to handle file uploads?
      callback()
      return
    }

    // This is electron.net, docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/net
    net
      .request(req)
      .on('response', (res) => {
        const chunks = []
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk))
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
          const blob = Buffer.concat(chunks)
          const type = res.headers['content-type'] || []
          if (type.includes('text/html') && blob.includes('<head>')) {
            // FIXME?
            const pos = blob.indexOf('<head>')
            // inject contains the Buffer with the injected HTML script
            callback(Buffer.concat([blob.slice(0, pos), inject, blob.slice(pos)]))
          } else {
            callback(blob)
          }
        })
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('error', err)
        callback()
      })
      .end()
  })
})
```

Comment: If your global variable is a simple string why not pass it as a query param of url, like this: `view.webContents.loadURL('http://localhost:3000?baz=qux');`. And in your react app you can parse the query params.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal It is not. I wanted to give a simple example but what I need to inject is a Web3 provider.

Comment: @J.Hesters does your React app already include `web3.js` library (if I understood your case correctly)? Then you could just pass in a provider URL string. You won't be able to pass in the library as global variable from electron to the page with contextIsolation enabled. Also I am not sure, what your code snippet `protocol.interceptBufferProtocol` has to do with your case (file upload? what https request shall be intercepted?). Looks a bit like an XY problem, which might get done easier. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on your issue.

Comment: If you are able to adjust the web app build: An alternative would be to provide an electron specific version of the React web app which extends your basic web version with added/bundled web3 functionality. This enhanced version could be included in your Electron build, while the web version remained untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers are outdated, use [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge) be sure to use [sendToHost()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer/#ipcrenderersendtohostchannel-args) instead of send()

```js
    // Preload (Isolated World)
    const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
      'electron',
      {
        doThing: () => ipcRenderer.sendToHost('do-a-thing')
      }
    )
    
    // Renderer (Main World)
    
    window.electron.doThing()
```

Comment: window.electron is undefined. Please update your answer with valid codes.

Comment: @Abbas the code still works with electron 16, you must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 9):

After doing some digging, I found a few pull requests for Electron that detail the issue you are having. The [first](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13134) describes a reproducible example very similar to the problem you are describing.

> #### Expected Behavior
>
> https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content
>   A preload script should be able to attach anything to the window or document with contextIsolation: true.
>
> #### Actual behavior
>
> Anything attached to the window in the preload.js just disappears in the renderer.

It seems the final comment explains that the expected behavior no longer works

> It was actually possible until recently, a PR with Isolated Worlds has changed the behavior.

The [second](https://github.com/kewde/electron-sandbox-boilerplate/issues/14) has a user suggest what they have found to be their solution:

> After many days of research and fiddling with the IPC, I've concluded that the best way is to go the protocol route.

I looked at the docs for [`BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) and [`BrowserView`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) as well as an [example](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#event-loaded) that shows the behavior that you desire, but these PRs suggest this is no longer possible (along this route).

### Possible Solution

Looking into the documentation, the `webContents` object you get from `view.webContents` has the function [executeJavaScript](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture), so you could try the following to set the global variable.

```
...
view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });
view.webContents.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
view.webContents.executeJavaScript("global.baz = 'qux';");
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to try `executeJavaScript` and I'm gonna give you the bounty for providing the most helpful answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: `executeJavaScript` doesn't work for us because it’s definitely after the page load, which, does not solve the task of preloading a script to define globals.

Answer (score 1):

So, [`executeJavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000056/javascript-how-to-stringify-a-class-after-calling-new) as suggested by Zapparatus ended up being part of the solution.

This is what's going on in `renderer.js`.

```
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
  window.communicator = {
    request: function(data) {
      const url = 'prefix://?data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest()
      req.open('GET', url)
      req.send();
    },
    receive: function(data) {
      alert('got: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
    }
  };
`)
const setContent = data => view.webContents.executeJavaScript(
  `window.communicator.receive(${JSON.stringify(data)})`
)
ipcRenderer.on('communicator', (event, message) => {
  setContent(`Hello, ${message}!`)
})
```

We ended up setting up a custom protocol, similar to how its been done [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-safe-ipc). In your `main.js` file set up the following:

```
const { app, session, protocol } = require('electron')
const { appWindows } = require('./main/app-run')
const { URL } = require('url')

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  {
    scheme: 'prefix',
    privileges: {
      bypassCSP: true, // ignore CSP, we won't need to patch CSP
      secure: true // allow requests from https context
    }
  }
])

app.on('ready', () => {
  const sess = session.fromPartition('my-view-partition')

  // https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#4-handle-session-permission-requests-from-remote-content
  sess.setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
    // Denies the permissions request
    const decision = false
    return callback(decision)
  })

  sess.protocol.registerStringProtocol('prefix', (req, callback) => {
    const url = new URL(req.url)
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(url.searchParams.get('data'))
      appWindows.main.webContents.send('prefix', data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Could not parse prefix request!')
    }
    const response = {
      mimeType: 'text/plain',
      data: 'ok'
    }
    callback(response)
  })
})
```

No `preload.js` or `postMessage` needed.