# JavaScript: How to stringify a class, after calling new

Tags: javascript, class, electron, ipc, stringify

**TL;DR:** I need to inject some JavaScript into a `BrowserView` in Electron using [`executeJavaScript`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback). This code needs to be class. How can I stringify the class?

I found out that you can stringify functions using `+`.

```
const fn = function() {
  console.log('Hello');
};
const functionToText = '' + fn;
console.log(functionToText);
// function() {
//   console.log('Hello');
// }
*/
```

But my problem is, how can you stringify classes? I need the string version of the following object created from the class with `new` to inject it.

```
class Person {
  constructor({ name }) {
    this.getName = () => name;
  }
}
const person = new Person({ name: 'John'});
const str = // somehow stringify person here
console.log(str);
// the person object
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`window.person = ${str}`);
```

**Edit:**

Here is how I ended up implementing it based on the accepted answer:

```
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(
  `window.person = new ${str}({ name: 'John' })`
);
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify(thingyouwanttostringify)?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm sorry, its late where I live  I updated the question with the real problem.

Comment: @JDunken Doesn't work, because the class has methods.

Comment: @J. Hesters  May I know why you declared in const type?

Comment: Can't be done, not the way you're describing. Just do `executeJavascript('window.person = new Person({ name: \'John\' });');` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the solution in your question.
The same approach that works for functions works for classes too.

```
class Person {
  constructor({ name }) {
    this.getName = () => name;
  }
}
const str = '' + Person;
console.log(str);
```

**Updated in response to additional data in question.**
You can't serialize an object and make it cross execution boundaries because it is no longer data at that point, but instead is running in memory.

One approach you could take is invoke all of the code inside the call to `executeJavaScript`

For example:

```
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
class Person {
  constructor({ name }) {
    this.getName = () => name;
  }
}

window.person = new Person({name: 'John'});
`);
```

Or alternatively

```
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
(function() {
    class Person {
      constructor({ name }) {
        this.getName = () => name;
      }
    }

    window.person = new Person({name: 'John'});
})();
`);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying. I want to stringify the class **after** calling `new`.

Comment: You can't transfer the object, because at that point it's no longer "just data".

Could you  execute the entire thing in the function call rather than trying to cross execution boundaries?
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`class Person { ...} window.person = new Person({name: John})`);

Or wrap it in an IIFE if the code is expected to be a single expression.

Comment: Thank you very much! I amended my question with how I implemented it, because in my real application I'm importing the class.